# Concatenating certain rows based on certain conditions in Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, concatenation, teradata, dynamic-sql

I have a table with the following structure:

```
Sr.No | Timestamp | Type
1        A          x
1        B          y
1        C          v 
1        D          w
2        E          j 
2        F          l
3        G          o
```

I want to calculate the time difference for all Sr.No and wherever the time difference is less than 12 hrs, I want to concatenate the "Type" column.
So, if A-B = 11 hrs and E-F = 10 hrs, the output should be:

```
Sr.No | Type
1       x + y
1       v 
1       w
2       j + l
3       o
```

How do I do this in Teradata SQL?

Comment: Can you details about datatypes & show some actual data? And why do you tag `sql-server` when it's Teradata?

Comment: Edited the tags. The data type in both is varchar and I can't show any actual data, but it has a similar structure

Comment: A Timestamp stored in a Varchar? Ouch. And what if there are more than two rows within that 12 hour difference? You need to elaborate on that.

Comment: `A` is not a valid timestamp value. How do you calculate the difference in hours between `A` and `B` for that example?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have knowledge of tera data but it seems to me that you are mainly interested in the sql. In the below sql i am simply subtracting timestamp value to find hour difference. You need to convert it according to tera data. Please find below the sample sql:

```
select t1.sno, t1.type | '+' |t2.type 
from tbl t1
inner join tbl t2 on t1.sno = t2.sno and t1.type <> t2.type
where t1.timestamp -t2.timestamp < 12
union 
select t3.sno,t3.type
from tbl t3
left join
(
    select t5.sno, t5.type,t6.type 
    from tbl t5
    inner join tbl t6 on t5.sno = t6.sno and t5.type <> t6.type
    where t5.timestamp -t6.timestamp < 12
) t4 on t3.sno = t4.sno and (t3.type=t4.type1 or t3.type=t4.type2)
where t4.sno is null
```